# Integrating Tor Browser and Python to get the same circute

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit, python, stem

This is a cross post from my [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723680/integrating-tor-and-python-to-get-the-same-circute) question(also I little edited).

Ok, my question is quite straightforward:

I want to use Python to make automated requests with [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) (or any other library which interacts with Tor making new circuits for automation) and then use the same circuit that I used for automation in Python in the *Tor Browser* for manual work (e.g. filling forms or captchas).

My main requirements is:

- First using a programming language(preferable Python) to *create new circuits* for some automated work.
- Then using the *Tor Browser with the same circuit* that I used with Python to do manual work.

I know there are *messy ways* around it but still I am quite stuck.

So the part I am stuck is getting the same circuit: I know you can use Tor with [`TOR_TRANSPROXY` and `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH`](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/26/can-you-use-the-tor-browser-without-tor-connection/), but what should do to allow the circuit made in Python with [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) to work with on the Tor Browser?

The only workaround I see is to create a proxy in Python after doing the automated stuff with [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/), then route it through the OS proxy settings and then using Tor with [`TOR_TRANSPROXY` and `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH`](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/26/can-you-use-the-tor-browser-without-tor-connection/) to get the same circuit, but again its *too messy* and lots of work.

Does anyone know a better way to do this, if I am right it should have something to do with [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) and the Tor browser, or do I have to go the *messy way*.

Thanks,
Dex Devlon.

Comment: I don't want to help too much since this sounds like you're writing a bot, but you can use stem to attach new streams to specific circuits (see the `__LeaveStreamsUnattached` option).

Comment: This seems really promising, I would take a look right away, if It fits my needs I would mark the question as answered. Thanks @Steve